# DEBUG:FASTLINK - What is this error?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, stl, visual-studio-2017

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    FILE *fPtr = fopen("english.txt", "r");

    if (fPtr == NULL) {
        cout << "Could not open the file." << endl;
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
    char word[100];
    map <string, int> freq;
    while (!feof(fPtr)) {
        fscanf(fPtr, "%s", word);
        freq[word]++;
    }
    multimap <int, string > freq_rev;
    map<string, int>::iterator it;
    for (it = freq.begin(); it != freq.end(); it++)
        freq_rev.insert(make_pair(it->second, it->first));

    multimap <int, string>::reverse_iterator myit;
    int count;
    for (myit = freq_rev.rbegin(), count = 0; count < 10; myit++, count++)
        cout << (*myit).second << " " << (*myit).first << endl;
    fclose(fPtr);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I am using Visual Studio 2017 for Data Structures course. Code above is supposed to look into the english.txt file which contains a lot of words, to detect frequency of these words, and print top 10 frequently used words.

Before getting to errors in the code, VS 17 gives this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbyBX.png):

> Could not find c:/Users/username/documents/visual studio
>   2017/Projects/projectname/projectname/Debug/projectname.obj'.projectname.exe
>   was built with /DEBUG:FASTLINK which requires object files for
>   debugging.
>
> Subsequent failures will be logged to the Debug pane of the Output
>   window.

I am not an experienced programmer, I googled but could not find something useful. What is this supposed to be, what should I do?

Comment: Please include the error as text.  And try a clean followed by a full rebuild.

Comment: The error doesn't have anything to do with your code or that you use `std::multimap`. Read again what the message says.

Comment: Well, `for (myit = freq_rev.rbegin(), count = 0; count < 10; myit++, count++)` is not correctr.  You never make sure `myit` is valid before you try and dereference it.

Comment: @RichardCritten I did.

Comment: @user0042 What is it saying? I really did not understand.

Comment: @Jacob It says that it can't find an object file that was created during the build process. Since you have that `/DEBUG:FASTLINK` project option set, you need that to start the program in the debugger.

Comment: Why the .obj file disappeared is hard to guess, it is not very healthy.  Just change the link option to get ahead.  Project > Properties > Linker > Debugging > "Generate Debug Info" = /DEBUG.

Answer (score 5):

The /DEBUG:FASTLINK is aimed at improving link times for the incremental developer loop inside Visual Studio and for medium to large size projects provides ~2x gains. More information about /DEBUG:FASTLINK, please refer to this blog:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/10/05/faster-c-build-cycle-in-vs-15-with-debugfastlink/

According to the error message, please make sure your project could build successful without any errors. It could make sure all files could be generated successful.

Then please check your project properties to make sure set **Generate Debug Info as Generate Debug Information optimized for faster links (/DEBUG:FASTLINK)** and set **Generate Full Program Database File as Yes**.

[image]

Comment: Please see the answer from @Chaohsiung-Huang . This is indeed a bug, that needs to be resolved by VS 2017 team.

Comment: This answer -from the comments here and below- appeared to be incorrect at the time of writing. It is now (for later versions of Visual Studio) definitely incorrect as the screenshot is now out of date (with the second highlighted setting removed) although the misleading error message still exists.

Answer (score 5):

I am using VS2017 and have met this issue recently. Alas I found the error report is wrong.  In my project properties, the value has nothing to do with the reported condition:

"Linker->Debugging->Generate Debug Info" is 
"Generate Debug Information /DEBUG", not /DEBUG:FASTLINK

And how to solve this? Make sure the fields follow have **different values** in project properties:

**Linker->Debugging->Generate Program Database File** 
v.s. 
**C/C++"->Output Files->Program Database File Name**

In my case they are the same, thus the report misunderstood the situation.
Change one of them, such as different file extension name or add an underline to a filename, etc.

Good Luck!

Comment: it seems like it now needs /DEBUG:FULL. /DEBUG alone is not enough.

Answer (score 3):

/DEBUG:FASTLINK option is avaliable in visual studio 2017 and later. To avoid the error,you can change the option to /DEBUG:FULL. you can follow these steps:

Open the project's **Property Pages** dialog box, find the **Linker->Debugging->Generate Debug Info**, then select the /DEBUG:FULL option.Hope it can help you!

By the way, you can click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/debug-generate-debug-info?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(VC.Project.VCLinkerTool.GenerateDebugInformation)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=vs-2019) to see the details of the option.